# how to load in table cell? the following is json data

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

```
[{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
}, {
    "firstName": "Anna",
    "lastName": "Smith"
}, {
    "firstName": "Peter",
    "lastName": "Jones"
}]
```

i have these type of json data, how could i load in table cell, what would be the key value for loading firstname and lastname?

Comment: is it [0]["firstName"]?

Comment: Can you show some code what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift version

```
 //create a struct to represent your data
 struct People {
     var firstName: String!
     var lastName: String!
 }

 //create an array to store your data in your class
 var peopleArray: [People]?

 //when the view loads, take the data you receive and parse it
 for person in dataReceived {
     let personToAdd = People(firstName: person["firstName"], lastName: person["lastName"]
     peopleArray.append(personToAdd)
 }

 //cell for row at index path
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("identifier")
 let personForCell = peopleArray[indexPath.row]
 cell.textLabel!.text = personForCell.firstName
 cell.detailTextLabel.text = personForCell.lastName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *responseArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // get JSON response from server or local to NSArray
    _responseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:yourJsonHere options:0 error:nil];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

    NSDictionary *row = _responseArray[indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:row[@"firstName"]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:row[@"lastName"]];
    return cell;
}
```

Change your `UITableViewCellStyle` accordingly or create your own labels for them.

Comment: There was no code shown in the original question (and so it is voted down) - but  the question contained the `swift` tag. This doesn't look like swift to me.

Comment: I dont care, I'll still help the guy where I can. If he knew the answer or know a developer he wouldn't have been here. My answer is better than no answer..